# MS Access (OLEDB) UPDATE Table under multiple conditions

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

Hello and apologies for the seeming simplicity of this question to some, but I am a mediocre programmer at best and I am dealing with critical data here.

I am trying to update one column (PArchiveStatus) in a table (Image) depending on whether some status `(ParchiveStatus) is ((100 OR 200) AND ((timestamp>'2014-11-14 00:00:00') AND (timestamp<'2016-02-05 00:00:00')))` in each row. ('Captured' is the name of the timestamp column)

*anything before and after those two dates cannot be touched*

I have come up with two variations, neither of which work (lol)

a little nudge in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

1. Variation
   `UPDATE [Image] SET [PArchiveStatus]='0' WHERE [PArchiveStatus] = 100 AND [Captured] BETWEEN '2014-11-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-05 00:00:00';`
2. Variation
   `UPDATE [Image] SET [PArchiveStatus]='0' WHERE [PArchiveStatus]=100 AND [Captured]>'2014-11-14 00:00:00';`

> and friend also told me about this
>   3. Variation
>   `UPDATE (SELECT * from Image where PArchiveStatus = 100) SET PArchiveStatus=0 Where Captured BETWEEN '2014-11-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-05 00:00:00'`

<strike>I should maybe mention that the date/time stamp in the table is not available in any other "format" than the one in the query, meaning it HAS to be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` (24 hour format) and I am to be honest not sure if I can use this format in a single-line query *(which by the way is another requirement for the solution, as I can only send single line updates into the database)*</strike>

Thank you for any kind soul helping me out on this.

## Solution

```
UPDATE [Image] SET [PArchiveStatus] = 0 WHERE [PArchiveStatus] = 100 AND [Captured] BETWEEN #2014-11-14# AND #2015-12-31#
```

Comment: this database exist as an .mdb file

I basically open the .mdb file in a tool and submit single line queries into it to do quick changes, rather than opening ms access and editing the content line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you try to update with a string. And do change the "dates" to true date values in the table. Then:

```
UPDATE 
    [Image] 
SET 
    [PArchiveStatus] = 0 
WHERE 
    [PArchiveStatus] = 100 
    AND 
    [Captured] > #2014-11-14 00:00:00#;
```

Comment: can I add a second [Captured] condition to this?

something like
    `...WHERE [PArchiveStatus] = 100 AND ([Captured] > #2014-11-14 00:00:00# AND [Captured] > #2014-11-14 00:00:00#);`

(can one even use brackets in these statements to weight them?)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Also you have `Between <somedate> And <anotherdate>`.

Comment: correction: (edited question as well): the Captured field's Datatype is actually set as a Date/Time, so it should be well formatted. From what I read I should be able to just use `#2014-11-14#` in the `BETWEEN` statements?

Comment: Yes, then you are all set.